# templated function design for extensibility

Tags: c++, c++11

*Sorry for the title, I couldn't find a more appropriate name. If anyone has a better one I will gladly change it.*

Let say we have a set of solid geometry objects:

```
struct ray { ... };
struct plane { ... };
struct box { .... };
struct sphere { .... };
```

I'm currently thinking on a templated function for intersection algorithms, so that we can create specialized versions of the function depending on the types to be checked at runtime:

```
template <typename operand_type1, 
          typename operand_type2> 
          RET_DATA check_intersection(operand_type1 operand1, operand_type2 operand2){ ... };
```

For a ray/shpehre intersection we would provide the following implementation:

```
template<> RET_DATA check_intersection<ray, sphere>(ray operand1, sphere operand2){ ... };
```

I left RET_DATA intentionally undefined as depending on each specialization we may want different information to be returned. For example for this case we can return the number of intersections (if any) and the associated points. For sphere-sphere we could return the volume of intersection. The problem is that we also need to create a new (return) type that the user of this template will need to know.

My current best candidate idea is to create a functor and specialize for each type. Inside the functor define a return struct with a common name to each specialization (i.e *result*):

```
/** templated functor */
template<typename T1, typename T2> struct check_intersect {
    typedef intersection_data<T1, T2> result;

    check_intersect(T1 operand1, T2 operand2) : operand1(operand1), operand2(operand2) {}

    result operator()(T1 operand1, T2 operand2){ ... }  
};

/** tempalted auxiliar return data type */
template<typename T1, typename T2> struct intersection_data { ... }
```

We would then provide specializations to both depending on the data types. This ends more or less in this usage pattern:

```
 check_intersect<ray, sphere>::result ret = check_intersect<ray, sphere>(my_ray, my_sphere);
```

The user still has to guess the interface for *result* although with modern IDEs the problem is somehow reduced. This is what I don't like about it.

Is this approach flawed? Any better design idea to solve the extensibility for upcoming solid-geometry types? Is this the most elegant approach?

Maybe templates are not the right tool for this, I could just provide different functions for each case....

Thank you.

Comment: I usually use virtual methods and inheritance from base classes for these types of things, but as I'm not experienced enough, I may likely change my design patterns in the future. (Just putting the other method out there)

Comment: The problem with that is that if you want to add the type "cone" you need to change the other classes and for the user of this library that  may not be possible. This way others can extend the library without touching it. But of course your method is as valid as this one.

Comment: Why don't you just do `typedef typename intersection_data<T1, T2>::result result;`

Comment: Ok that helps having less verbosity, like using auto keyword. But that's not the point of the question or I have misunderstood you. I'm asking if this functor approach is the best one, knowing that the user of the library will need to know how result interface is depending on the type of intersection check (will have different members).

Comment: "Maybe templates are not the right tool for this, I could just provide different functions for each case...." I don't see why you don't just use overloading here. `check_intersect<ray, sphere>(my_ray, my_sphere);` the template parameters can be deduced, no need to set them explicitly. `check_intersect<ray, sphere>::result` sound very metaprogramming-like IMO. What about `intersection<ray,sphere> my_i = insersect(my_ray, my_sphere);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use a template unless there's a general-case implementation. Unless you actually have a function body for `template< typename x, typename y > check_intersection( x, y )`, don't declare it.
2. Use overloading instead of template specialization. Overloading is the tool designed to solve this kind of problem. Specialization is different. It's OK to use specific overloads together with general templates.
3. Use a base class for the different RET_DATA types. This doesn't need to have a `virtual` destructor if you bind to a constant reference:

   ```
   check_intersect_result const &sect = check_intersect( my_sphere, my_cone );
   ```

   This does *not* slice the return value. The correct destructor will be called even if it's not `virtual`. But you can use `virtual` if you like.

   The issue goes away completely if you use C++11 `auto`. Then you don't even need a base class.

   ```
   auto &&sect = check_intersect( my_sphere, my_cone );
   ```

   This is nice precisely because the user *doesn't* need to know the return type, to use the function.
4. Separate plain functions and metafunctions are better than umbrella classes with member `operator()` and `result_type`. For extensibility, it's easier to add new free functions and metafunction specializations than to modify a monolithic class.
5. It might not be a bad idea to make an `intersection_result` meta-function, e.g. `intersection_result< sphere, cone >::type`, but I would avoid requiring it just to call the function.

Comment: Thank your for the tips. I would like to avoid virtual destructor at all, a tradeof for speed (as this will be called several times at runtime). Your idea of the const reference will do the trick. I will leave this open for today just in case there are better ideas out there.